# Connect to SSH using paramiko throue TOR

Tags: python, paramiko

I want know how to add TOR / PROXY to this connection:

```
def check_server(host, user, password, port=22):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    #FAILED APPROCH
    #proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand("127.0.0.1:9010")

    if is_work_sshd(host,port):
        return 2

    try:
        ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
        ssh.close()
    except:
        return 1

    return 0
```

I made google search lot of time but didn't found any answer to this question !
And there is any way to do it with PHP even with PHPSECLIB :(

If you have answer with python you're welcome :)